# build is not able to build a project in react

Tags: reactjs, build, craco

I am trying to build my project in VSCode and this is the error I get. I am not sure whewre I am going wrong. The following is my css file.

```
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar-title:hover {
  color: yellow !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

This is the error:

> mira@4.2.0 build
> craco build

craco:  *** Cannot find ESLint loader (eslint-loader). ***
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file:

```
    2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/.css:2
```

Read more here: https://cra.link/failed-to-minify

Any recommendations please? Thank you in advance